# Why can we say `arr.inject(:+)` but have to say `arr.map(&:to_s)`?

Tags: ruby

It seems that we can always use `&:+`. Why can `inject` take `:+` while `map` has to take `&:to_s`?  If the reason is that `map` can't take a symbol but must take a block, then would it make sense if `map` takes a symbol too?

```
[1,3,5].inject(:+)   # => 9
[1,3,5].inject(&:+)  # => 9
[1,3,5].map(&:to_s)  # => ["1", "3", "5"]
[1,3,5].map(:to_s)   # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Comment: @user2864740 I saw in another post that `&:to_s` returns a block

Comment: Considering that you can write `arr.inject(:+)` or `arr.inject(&:+)`, considering changing your question to why [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) does not have a form that permits the argument to be a symbol, as [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aka `reduce`) does. Isn't that what you mean?

Comment: yeah, if `inject` can take a symbol, then why doesn't it, at least in the above case, make sense for `map` to take a symbol too?

Answer (score 5):

It is by design. `inject` allows an alternative syntax to take a symbol while `map` always requires a block.

Probably the reason symbol argument is allowed in `inject` but not in `map` is because `inject` always returns the resulting object of iteration, whereas `map` is designed to return an `Enumerator` instance when a block is absent. And in case the block is absent, it would become complicated if it had to see whether a symbol argument is provided in order to decide whether to return an `Enumerator` or the mapped `Array` instance. So, the Ruby designers made a simple rule for methods like `map` that the absence of a block means the return value would be an `Enumerator`.

Ironically, a disadvantage for `inject` to allow a symbol is that a symbol cannot be passed as the initial value in `inject`. But probably, the designers of Ruby decided that there would be rare use case for that.

Comment: `:to_s` is also a symbol. Please provide applicable references/examples to clarify the behavior.

Comment: @sawa is there disadvantage if `map` can take a symbol too?

Comment: Think harder. There's got to be a good reason only `inject` permits it's argument to be a symbol. (I know not.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think I actually know. I will add it.

Comment: @sawa That explanation of why map does not support symbol is awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. Specifically, `inject`/`reduce` don't require the full symbol-to-proc syntax (`&:+`) but instead they allow to pass just a symbol (`:+`) (which a different behavior).

Please note that, in this specific case, passing a symbol is not the same of passing a proc derived from the symbol.

[From the Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

> Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation, specified by **a block** or **a symbol** that names a method or operator.
>
> **If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo.** In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know why `map` doesn't permit its argument to be a symbol.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If that's the case, it's implicit in my response. But just in case, here's the response. His assumption is that `:+` and `&:+` are the same thing, whereas they are not. The former is a symbol, the latter is a proc from a symbol. `map` doesn't accept a symbol because the method was designed to accept a block/proc and not a symbol.

Comment: oh I did say "If the reason is that map can't take a symbol but must take a block, then would it make sense if map takes a symbol too?"

Comment: @太極者無極而生 that's a subjective question, which is outside the scope of SO. Personally, I don't see any good reason I should be able to pass a symbol, because it would have the same behavior of `&:to_s` which is semantically different (and short enough). `inject` instead have different facets and passing a symbol or a block will result in a different behavior.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Will greatly appreciate if you can elaborate on your last line in previous comment.  What different behavior can be seen?  Sawa's answer provides some details, are ypu referring to same difference?

Comment: @WandMaker I explained the two differences in my answer. They are highlighted in bold.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti. Got it now...had to read it few times for it to sink in

Comment: I assumed that the OP realized that `inject(:+)` was not shorthand for `inject(&:+)`, but perhaps I was wrong.